# Create NSTableView using Storyboard

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

#### My steps using storyboard

1. Create a Mac Cocoa app using storyboard. Drag a Table View from the right sidebar onto the storyboard.
2. Let the pre-existing ViewController to follow `NSTableViewDataSource` protocol. Implement two methods in `ViewController.m`: `numberOfRowsInTableView:` returns 10 and `tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:` returns @"321".
3. In storyboard, connect the Table View's delegate and dataSource to (the only) View Controller.

#### The Problem

Every cell displays "Table View Cell" rather than the data I want to fill. In spite of that, `tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:` was indeed called 10 times.

#### The alternative using .xib

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p5U94-uRCOo

1. Use .xib rather than .storyboard. Drag a Table View from the right sidebar onto the storyboard.
2. Create a class MyTableViewController who follows `NSTableViewDataSource` protocol. Implement the same two methods.
3. In xib, drag a new object to the object. Change its class to MyTableViewController and connect the object to the table view's dataSource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table view needs to be cell based not view based. Loot at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/).

`tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:` is for cell based tables and

`- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row` is for view based table views.

Comment: Ha, thank you a lot mate! I was told view based cells are superior in some way so I used them.